# Where do I change this TextView to use a WebView?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, textview

OK, I'm working on the chapter 9 tutorial in Android Boot Camp and I'm having...actually a few issues. The book was written for the older versions of Android Studio but my class is using the latest version. I've done my best to look up tutorials for the latest version but they've become quite rare.

Chapter 9 covers a Master/Detail flow tutorial that some things have worked in and others have not.

Where I stand now is a TextView/WebView issue.

I tried simply converting the WebView to match TextView but then .loadUrl won't work and when I use WebView I get an "unexpected cast error. Layout tag was TextView." And Android studio won't tell me where the layout tag was declared so I'm currently combing through all the files line by line. I'm not certain if this source layout tag is in an .xml, a .java or if I should be looking in the manifest.

I believe this means I have to change the source layout to WebView though I can't find anything in the chapter itself about it except ensuring I have the correct import.

```
package com.example.bikeandbarge;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.bikeandbarge.dummy.DummyContent;

public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";


private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;


public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.content);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail, container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem.id.equals("1")) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos, container, false);
    }
    if (mItem.id.equals("2")) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tour, container, false);
    }
    // Can not get this to update to WebView-not certain where the layout tab is textView
    //if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
    //            ((WebView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.item_detail )).loadUrl( mItem.item_url ); }
    //Can replace WebView with TextView but won't recognize .loadUrl without WebView
    if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
        ((WebView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.item_detail )).loadUrl( mItem.item_url );

    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

I would love for this to run with loadUrl actually working.

Neither WebView nor TextView will allow me to run the program. The apk file simply can't be compiled for me to even test it. I'd like to at least get to a point where I can compile the apk file and attempt to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the layout file **item_detail.xml**(or is it **fragment_item_detail.xml** inn the book?) and change the `<TextView>`-element to `<WebView>`. Then the "Unexpected cast error" should go away.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out there's quite a bit more different naming conventions between the older and newer versions of Android Studio than I originally thought. Found where it auto-declared textView in the item_detail.xml, changed it to webview and everything now works.

Answer (score 0):

In your webView and manifest add the following code:

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        .....            
 >
```

> In Your Layout where the webView is

```
<WebView
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....        
  ></WebView>
```